# hadoop bzip2 xml inputformat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have xml file which I am able to split so that different maps get xml block of data (using custom recordreader).

Now I want to do this for file which is bzip compressed xml file.

Everywhere documentation says bzip says its splittable.

If it is splittable, then my previous code should work without any changes. But it is not working.

hadoop version is hadoop-1.2.1

I DON'T want https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop. I want to know whats happening than copying code.

Error information:

```
13/10/10 06:52:49 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:admin cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost/xmlinputformat/_xmlinputformat_sample.xml.bz2
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost/xmlinputformat/_xmlinputformat_sample.xml.bz2
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
    at com.rhl.xmlinputformat.XmlInputFormat.listStatus(XmlInputFormat.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    at com.rhl.xmlinputformat.XmlInputFormat.getSplits(XmlInputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1054)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at com.rhl.xmlinputformat.XmlInputFormatDriver.run(XmlInputFormatDriver.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.rhl.xmlinputformat.XmlInputFormatDriver.main(XmlInputFormatDriver.java:260)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it is not working"? Do you get a stacktrace? Give us some more details on the problem.

Comment: error information added

Comment: So the error looks like it's saying that there's no file in HDFS at the location: /xmlinputformat/_xmlinputformat_sample.xml.bz2. Are you sure it's there? if you do 'hadoop fs -ls /xmlinputformat' as the admin user is that file listed?